# ReactJS : How can get value in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF0Dy.png) Im have Object , but how can get keys + value in this (main : , weather : , clouds: , cors : , ... )
Im try use map but can't go next entry
[My demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZdnp.png)
Sorry im bad english . thanks alot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please attach the code as code instead of an image?

Answer (score 1):

Please, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). This is how you get both the key and value of an object.

```js
const foobar = {main: "hello", clouds = "world", cors: 1}
const keypairs = Object.entries(foobar);

//looping
keypairs.map(([key, value]) => { // do something });
```

Answer (score -1):

just replace value with value.main/ value.weather and it will work

andd one thing cities.map() is not enough you dont need cities.list.map()

good luck!